# How to extract bandwidth / Wavelength value from multispectral images?

Tags: python, feature-extraction

I collected multispectral images through Rededge MX. I used some codes for extracting these data, but only metadata was found from that analysis. For example, I have Blue, Green, Red, NIR, and Rededge images. I needed to find out the average wavelength of each image, But following the micasense tutorial code, I only got the center wavelengths of each image: 475 for blue, 717 for Rededge, 560 for Green, 668 for Red, and 842 for NIR. Also, bandwidth was fixed for all images. I need your support regarding this issue. Thank you

Comment: the center wavelengths and bandwidths are in the datasheet of the camera. how is this a programming question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When we calculate any of the vegetation indices, there are some variations in the band value which leads us to calculate NDVI ((NIR-Red/NIR+Red) using this equation) or other indices. If the band value varies, there must be a way to extract the specific band value for that specific image. I know the center wavelength and bandwidth is given in the micasense sheet, but I need to extract the band value which differs from time to time during data acquisition.